# How to read specific lines from a file (by line number)?

Tags: python, file, line

I'm using a `for` loop to read a file, but I only want to read specific lines, say line `#26` and `#30`. Is there any built-in feature to achieve this?

Comment: Possible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/620367/python-how-to-jump-to-a-particular-line-in-a-huge-text-file

Answer (score 335, accepted):

If the file to read is big, and you don't want to read the whole file in memory at once:

```
fp = open("file")
for i, line in enumerate(fp):
    if i == 25:
        # 26th line
    elif i == 29:
        # 30th line
    elif i > 29:
        break
fp.close()
```

Note that `i == n-1` for the `n`th line.

---

In Python 2.6 or later:

```
with open("file") as fp:
    for i, line in enumerate(fp):
        if i == 25:
            # 26th line
        elif i == 29:
            # 30th line
        elif i > 29:
            break
```

Comment: +1 Better solution than mine if the entire file isn't loaded into memory as in `linecache`. Are you sure that `enumerate(fp)` doesn't do that?

Comment: `enumerate(x)` uses `x.next`, so it doesn't need the entire file in memory.

Comment: My small beef with this is that A) You want to use with instead of the open / close pair and thus keep the body short, B) But the body is not that short. Sounds like a trade-off between speed/space and being Pythonic. I am not sure what the best solution would be.

Comment: Great. I like SO for that precise reason too. I'll add a link to your answer into mine.

Comment: with is overrated, python got along fine for over 13 years without it

Comment: Since this is from '10 and IDK when `io` was added, can someone comment as to whether one should simple use the above for reading in a stream v `io.open`?

Comment: @kuanb `io.open` is an alias for `open`.  `open()` will work without any issues.

Comment: @Dan D. Electricity is overrated, mankind got along fine for over 200 thousand years without it. ;-) 'with' is making it more secure, more readable, and one line shorter.

Comment: Is the same thing applicable for `python3.x` also? can you update?

Answer (score 200):

The quick answer:

```
f=open('filename')
lines=f.readlines()
print lines[25]
print lines[29]
```

or:

```
lines=[25, 29]
i=0
f=open('filename')
for line in f:
    if i in lines:
        print i
    i+=1
```

There is a more elegant solution for extracting many lines: [linecache](http://docs.python.org/library/linecache.html) (courtesy of ["python: how to jump to a particular line in a huge text file?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620367/python-how-to-jump-to-a-particular-line-in-a-huge-text-file), a previous stackoverflow.com question).

Quoting the python documentation linked above:

```
>>> import linecache
>>> linecache.getline('/etc/passwd', 4)
'sys:x:3:3:sys:/dev:/bin/sh\n'
```

Change the `4` to your desired line number, and you're on. Note that 4 would bring the fifth line as the count is zero-based.

If the file might be very large, and cause problems when read into memory, it might be a good idea to take [@Alok's advice and use enumerate()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081836/reading-specific-lines-only-python/2081880#2081880).

**To Conclude:**

- Use `fileobject.readlines()` or `for line in fileobject` as a quick solution for small files.
- Use `linecache` for a more elegant solution, which will be quite fast for reading many files, possible repeatedly.
- Take [@Alok's advice and use `enumerate()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081836/reading-specific-lines-only-python/2081880#2081880) for files which could be very large, and won't fit into memory. Note that using this method might slow because the file is read sequentially.

Comment: Nice.  I just looked at the source of `linecache` module, and looks like it reads the whole file in memory.  So, if random access is more important than size optimization, `linecache` is the best method.

Comment: with linecache.getlin('some_file', 4) I get the 4th line, not the 5th.

Comment: fun fact: if you use a set instead of the list in the second example, you get O(1) running time. Look up in a list is O(n). Internally sets are represented as hashes, and thats why you get the O(1) running time. not a big deal in this example, but If using a large list of numbers, and care about efficiency, then sets are the way to go.

Comment: `linecache` now appears to only work for python source files

Comment: You can also use `linecache.getlines('/etc/passwd')[0:4]` to read in the first, second, third and fourth lines.

Answer (score 42):

For the sake of offering another solution:

```
import linecache
linecache.getline('Sample.txt', Number_of_Line)
```

I hope this is quick and easy :)

Comment: Hope this is most optimal solution .

Comment: This reads the whole file into memory. You might as well call file.read().split('\n') then use array index lookups to get the line of interest...

Comment: Could you provide an example @duhaime

Comment: @anon `''.join(file.readlines()).split('\n'))[5:10]` gives you row 6 to 10 for example. Not recommended, as it reads the whole file into memory.

Comment: Here is an example and it worked to me:  def get_version():
    versionLine = linecache.getline('config.php', 4)
    version = versionLine[19:24]
    return version

Answer (score 37):

A fast and compact approach could be:

```
def picklines(thefile, whatlines):
  return [x for i, x in enumerate(thefile) if i in whatlines]
```

this accepts any open file-like object `thefile` (leaving up to the caller whether it should be opened from a disk file, or via e.g a socket, or other file-like stream) and a set of zero-based line indices `whatlines`, and returns a list, with low memory footprint and reasonable speed.  If the number of lines to be returned is huge, you might prefer a generator:

```
def yieldlines(thefile, whatlines):
  return (x for i, x in enumerate(thefile) if i in whatlines)
```

which is basically only good for looping upon -- note that the only difference comes from using rounded rather than square parentheses in the `return` statement, making a list comprehension and a generator expression respectively.

Further note that despite the mention of "lines" and "file" these functions are much, **much** more general -- they'll work on **any** iterable, be it an open file or any other, returning a list (or generator) of items based on their progressive item-numbers.  So, I'd suggest using more appropriately general names;-).

Comment: @ephemient, I disagree -- the genexp reads smoothly and perfectly.

Comment: Excellent and elegant solution, thanks! Indeed, even large files should be supported, with the generator expression. Can't get more elegant than this, can it? :)

Comment: Nice solution, how does this compare to the one proposed by @AdamMatan? The Adam solution could be faster as it exploits additional information (line numbers monotonically increasing) which could lead to an early stop. I have a 10GB file which I cannot load into memory.

Comment: @Mannaggia It's not emphasized enough in this answer, but `whatlines` should be a `set`, because `if i in whatlines` will execute faster with a set rather than a (sorted) list. I didn't notice it first and instead devised my own ugly solution with sorted list (where I didn't have to scan a list each time, while `if i in whatlines` does just that), but difference in performance was negligible (with my data) and this solution is much more elegant.

Answer (score 18):

For the sake of completeness, here is one more option.

Let's start with a definition from [python docs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/glossary.html#term-slice):

> **slice** An object usually containing a portion of a sequence. A slice is created using the subscript notation, [] with colons between numbers when several are given, such as in variable_name[1:3:5]. The bracket (subscript) notation uses slice objects internally (or in older versions, __getslice__() and __setslice__()).

Though the slice notation is not directly applicable to iterators in general, the `itertools` package contains a replacement function:

```
from itertools import islice

# print the 100th line
with open('the_file') as lines:
    for line in islice(lines, 99, 100):
        print line

# print each third line until 100
with open('the_file') as lines:
    for line in islice(lines, 0, 100, 3):
        print line
```

The additional advantage of the function is that it does not read the iterator until the end. So you can do more complex things:

```
with open('the_file') as lines:
    # print the first 100 lines
    for line in islice(lines, 100):
        print line

    # then skip the next 5
    for line in islice(lines, 5):
        pass

    # print the rest
    for line in lines:
        print line
```

And to answer the original question:

```
# how to read lines #26 and #30
In [365]: list(islice(xrange(1,100), 25, 30, 4))
Out[365]: [26, 30]
```

Comment: By far the best approach when working with large files.  My program went from consuming 8GB+ to almost nothing.  The tradoff was CPU usage which went from ~15% to ~40% but the actual processing of the file was 70% faster. I'll take that tradoff all day long.  Thanks you! 

Comment: This seems the most pythonic to me. Thanks!

Comment: Most pythonic for now!

Answer (score 15):

if you want line 7

```
line = open("file.txt", "r").readlines()[7]
```

Comment: Neat. But how do you `close()` the file when opening it this way?

Comment: @0sh do we need to close?

Comment: yes. we need to close after this.When we open a file using "with" ... it closes itself.

Comment: `with open("file.txt", "r") as file:`                 `line = file.readlines()[7]`. But mind that this reads the whole file into memory.

Answer (score 14):

Reading files is incredible fast. Reading a 100MB file takes less than 0.1 seconds (see my article [Reading and Writing Files with Python](https://martin-thoma.com/reading-and-writing-files-with-python/)). Hence you should read it completely and then work with the single lines.

What most answer here do is not wrong, but bad style. Opening files should always be done with [`with`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) as it makes sure that the file is closed again.

So you should do it like this:

```
with open("path/to/file.txt") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
print(lines[26])  # or whatever you want to do with this line
print(lines[30])  # or whatever you want to do with this line
```

### Huge files

If you happen to have a huge file and memory consumption is a concern, you can process it line by line:

```
with open("path/to/file.txt") as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        pass  # process line i
```

Comment: IMO it is a really bad style to read an entire file of unknown lenght, just only to get the first 30 lines .. what is about memory consumption .. and what is about endless streams?

Comment: @return42 It depends very much on the application. For many, it is totally fine to assume that a text file has a way lower size than the available memory. If you happen to have potentially huge files, I've edited my answer.

Comment: thanks for your addition, which is the same as alok [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2081880/300130). And sorry no, I don't think this depends on the application. IMO it is always better not read more lines then  you need.

Comment: "Reading files is incredibly fast" I take issue with this. Reading files is, in fact, extremely slow, and data intensive programs will go out of their way to do it as little as possible. 0.1 seconds is nowhere near "fast" in computing terms. If you're only doing it once maybe it's okay (in some cases), but if you do that 1000 times it will take 100 seconds and that is nowhere near acceptable in most cases.

Comment: @michael dorst: I completely agree. It depends on your application, but we need to consider that he has to read the file anyway. The question is: what is the speed difference between reading line 26 and 30 only and reading a file with e.g. 500 lines. I'm assuming it's not way more, because that I would have expected to be mentioned.

Answer (score 10):

Some of these are lovely, but it can be done much more simply:

```
start = 0 # some starting index
end = 5000 # some ending index
filename = 'test.txt' # some file we want to use

with open(filename) as fh:
    data = fin.readlines()[start:end]

print(data)
```

That will use simply list slicing, it loads the whole file, but most systems will minimise memory usage appropriately, it's faster than most of the methods given above, and works on my 10G+ data files. Good luck!

Answer (score 7):

If your large text file `file` is strictly well-structured (meaning every line has the same length `l`), you could use for `n`-th line

```
with open(file) as f:
    f.seek(n*l)
    line = f.readline() 
    last_pos = f.tell()
```

**Disclaimer** This does only work for files with the same length!

Answer (score 5):

You can do a [seek()](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html) call which positions your read head to a specified byte within the file. This won't help you unless you know exactly how many bytes (characters) are written in the file before the line you want to read. Perhaps your file is strictly formatted (each line is X number of bytes?) or, you could count the number of characters yourself (remember to include invisible characters like line breaks) if you really want the speed boost.

Otherwise, you do have to read every line prior to the line you desire, as per one of the many solutions already proposed here.

Answer (score 5):

```py
with open("test.txt", "r") as fp:
   lines = fp.readlines()
print(lines[3])
```

test.txt is filename
prints line number four in test.txt

Comment: for larger file, readlines does not scale at all.

Answer (score 4):

```
def getitems(iterable, items):
  items = list(items) # get a list from any iterable and make our own copy
                      # since we modify it
  if items:
    items.sort()
    for n, v in enumerate(iterable):
      if n == items[0]:
        yield v
        items.pop(0)
        if not items:
          break

print list(getitems(open("/usr/share/dict/words"), [25, 29]))
# ['Abelson\n', 'Abernathy\n']
# note that index 25 is the 26th item
```

Comment: Roger, my favorite guy! This could benefit from a with statement.

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
>>> with open('a', 'r') as fin: lines = fin.readlines()
>>> for i, line in enumerate(lines):
      if i > 30: break
      if i == 26: dox()
      if i == 30: doy()
```

Comment: True, this is less efficient than the one by Alok, but mine uses a with statement ;)

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind importing then [fileinput](http://pydoc.org/2.5.1/fileinput.html) does exactly what you need (this is you can read the line number of the current line)

Answer (score 3):

I prefer this approach because it's more general-purpose, i.e. you can use it on a file, on the result of `f.readlines()`, on a `StringIO` object, whatever:

```
def read_specific_lines(file, lines_to_read):
   """file is any iterable; lines_to_read is an iterable containing int values"""
   lines = set(lines_to_read)
   last = max(lines)
   for n, line in enumerate(file):
      if n + 1 in lines:
          yield line
      if n + 1 > last:
          return

>>> with open(r'c:\temp\words.txt') as f:
        [s for s in read_specific_lines(f, [1, 2, 3, 1000])]
['A\n', 'a\n', 'aa\n', 'accordant\n']
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's my little 2 cents, for what it's worth ;)

```
def indexLines(filename, lines=[2,4,6,8,10,12,3,5,7,1]):
    fp   = open(filename, "r")
    src  = fp.readlines()
    data = [(index, line) for index, line in enumerate(src) if index in lines]
    fp.close()
    return data


# Usage below
filename = "C:\\Your\\Path\\And\\Filename.txt"
for line in indexLines(filename): # using default list, specify your own list of lines otherwise
    print "Line: %s\nData: %s\n" % (line[0], line[1])
```

Answer (score 3):

A better and minor change for Alok Singhal's answer

```
fp = open("file")
for i, line in enumerate(fp,1):
    if i == 26:
        # 26th line
    elif i == 30:
        # 30th line
    elif i > 30:
        break
fp.close()
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this very simply with this syntax that someone already mentioned, but it's by far the easiest way to do it:

```
inputFile = open("lineNumbers.txt", "r")
lines = inputFile.readlines()
print (lines[0])
print (lines[2])
```

Answer (score 3):

### Fairly quick and to the point.

To print certain lines in a text file.  Create a "lines2print" list and then
just print when the enumeration is "in" the lines2print list.
To get rid of extra '\n' use line.strip() or line.strip('\n').
I just like "list comprehension" and try to use when I can.
I like the "with" method to read text files in order to prevent
leaving a file open for any reason.

```
lines2print = [26,30] # can be a big list and order doesn't matter.

with open("filepath", 'r') as fp:
    [print(x.strip()) for ei,x in enumerate(fp) if ei in lines2print]
```

or if list is small just type in list as a list into the comprehension.

```
with open("filepath", 'r') as fp:
    [print(x.strip()) for ei,x in enumerate(fp) if ei in [26,30]]
```

Answer (score 1):

File objects have a .readlines() method which will give you a list of the contents of the file, one line per list item. After that, you can just use normal list slicing techniques.

http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.readlines

Answer (score 1):

@OP, you can use enumerate

```
for n,line in enumerate(open("file")):
    if n+1 in [26,30]: # or n in [25,29] 
       print line.rstrip()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
file = '/path/to/file_to_be_read.txt'
with open(file) as f:
    print f.readlines()[26]
    print f.readlines()[30]
```

Using the with statement, this opens the file, prints lines 26 and 30, then closes the file. Simple!

Comment: this isn't a valid answer. after the first call to `readlines()` the iterator will be exhausted and the second call will either return an empty list or throw an error (can't remember which)

Answer (score 1):

To print line# 3,

```
line_number = 3

with open(filename,"r") as file:
current_line = 1
for line in file:
    if current_line == line_number:
        print(file.readline())
        break
    current_line += 1
```

Original author: Frank Hofmann

Answer (score 0):

To print desired line.
To print line above/below required line.

```
def dline(file,no,add_sub=0):
    tf=open(file)
    for sno,line in enumerate(tf):
        if sno==no-1+add_sub:
         print(line)
    tf.close()
```

execute---->dline("D:\dummy.txt",6)  i.e dline("file path", line_number, if you want upper line of the searched line give 1 for lower -1 this is optional default value will be taken 0)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read specific lines, such as line starting after some threshold line then you can use the following codes,
`file  = open("files.txt","r")
lines = file.readlines() ## convert to list of lines
datas  = lines[11:]  ## raed the specific lines`

Answer (score 0):

Do Not Use `readlines`!

My solutition is:

```py
with open(filename) as f:
    specify = [26, 30]
    results = list(
        map(lambda line: line[1],
            filter(lambda line: line[0] in specify,
                   enumerate(f))
            )
    )
```

Test as follow for a `6.5G` file:

```py
import time

filename = 'a.txt'
start = time.time()
with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    for i in range(10_000_000):
        f.write(f'{str(i)*100}\n')       
end1 = time.time()

with open(filename) as f:
    specify = [26, 30]
    results = list(
        map(lambda line: line[1],
            filter(lambda line: line[0] in specify,
                   enumerate(f))
            )
    )
end2 = time.time()
print(f'write time: {end1-start}')
print(f'read time: {end2-end1}')
# write time: 14.38945460319519
# read time: 8.380386352539062
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with one of the simplest logic of splitting the string in an array or List.

```
f = open('filepath')
r = f.read()
s = r.split("\n")
n = [linenumber1, linenumber2] # [26, 29] in your 
                               #case
for x in n:
  print(s[x-1])
f.close()
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this would work

```
 open_file1 = open("E:\\test.txt",'r')
 read_it1 = open_file1.read()
 myline1 = []
 for line1 in read_it1.splitlines():
 myline1.append(line1)
 print myline1[0]
```

Comment: There were already a dozen readline methods when you posted this--adding another just adds clutter

Answer (score -2):

```
f = open(filename, 'r')
totalLines = len(f.readlines())
f.close()
f = open(filename, 'r')

lineno = 1
while lineno < totalLines:
    line = f.readline()

    if lineno == 26:
        doLine26Commmand(line)

    elif lineno == 30:
        doLine30Commmand(line)

    lineno += 1
f.close()
```

Comment: this is as unpythonic as it gets.

Comment: Gives the wrong result, as you can't use readlines and readline like that (they each change the current read position).

Comment: I'm sorry for having overlooked a HUGE error in my first code. The error has been corrected and the current code should work as expected. Thanks for pointing out my error, Roger Pate.

Answer (score -2):

Reading from specific line:

```
n = 4   # for reading from 5th line
with open("write.txt",'r') as t:
     for i,line in enumerate(t):
         if i >= n:             # i == n-1 for nth line
            print(line)
```

Comment: thats no built in feautre