# Selecting and printing specific rows of text file

Tags: python, file, line

I have a very large (~8 gb) text file that has very long lines.  I would like to pull out lines in selected ranges of this file and put them in another text file.  In fact my question is very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081836/reading-specific-lines-only-python) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/python-read-file-line-by-line-into-array) but I keep getting stuck when I try to select a range of lines instead of a single line.

So far this is the only approach I have gotten to work:

```
lines = readin.readlines()
out1.write(str(lines[5:67]))
out2.write(str(lines[89:111]))
```

However this gives me a list and I would like to output a file with a format identical to the input file (one line per row)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call join on the ranges.

```
lines = readin.readlines()
out1.write(''.join(lines[5:67]))
out2.write(''.join(lines[89:111]))
```

Comment: It should be out1.write(''.join(lines[5:67])) and same for out2 because readlines doesn't remove end of lines

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer - you don't just read 8 GB into memory unless you have a very good reason to do it.

Answer (score 2):

might i suggest not storing the entire file (since it is large) as per one of your links?

```
f = open('file')
n = open('newfile', 'w')
for i, text in enumerate(f):
    if i > 4 and i < 68:
        n.write(text)
    elif i > 88 and i < 112:
        n.write(text)
    else:
        pass
```

i'd also recommend using 'with' instead of opening and closing the file, but i unfortunately am not allowed to upgrade to a new enough version of python for that here : (.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you should think of when facing a problem like this, is to avoid reading the entire file into memory at once. `readlines()` will do that, so that specific method should be avoided.

Luckily, we have an excellent standard library in Python, [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice). `itertools` has lot of useful functions, and one of them is [`islice`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice). `islice` iterates over an iterable (such as lists, generators, file-like objects etc.) and returns a generator containing the range specified:

> `itertools.islice(iterable, start, stop[, step])`
>
> > Make an iterator that returns selected elements from the iterable. If start is non-zero,
> >     then elements from the iterable are skipped until start is reached.
> >     Afterward, elements are returned consecutively unless step is set
> >     higher than one which results in items being skipped. If stop is None,
> >     then iteration continues until the iterator is exhausted, if at all;
> >     otherwise, it stops at the specified position. Unlike regular slicing,
> >     islice() does not support negative values for start, stop, or step.
> >     Can be used to extract related fields from data where the internal
> >     structure has been flattened (for example, a multi-line report may
> >     list a name field on every third line)

Using this information, together with the [str.join](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.join) method, you can e.g. extract lines 10-19 by using this simple code:

```
from itertools import islice

# Add the 'wb' flag if you use Windows
with open('huge_data_file.txt', 'wb') as data_file: 
    txt = '\n'.join(islice(data_file, 10, 20))
```

Note that when looping over the file object, the newline char is stripped from the lines, so you need to set *\n* as the joining char.

Answer (score 0):

(Partial Answer) In order to make your current approach work you'll have to write line by line. For instance:

```
lines = readin.readlines()

for each in lines[5:67]:
    out1.write(each)

for each in lines[89:111]:
    out2.write(each)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
path = "c:\\someplace\\"
```

*Open 2 text files.  One for reading and one for writing*

```
f_in = open(path + "temp.txt", 'r')
f_out = open(path + output_name, 'w')
```

*go through each line of the input file*

```
for line in f_in:
    if i_want_to_write_this_line == True:
        f_out.write(line)
```

*close the files when done*

```
f_in.close()
f_out.close()
```