# Basic python file-io variables with enumerate

Tags: python, file-io, enumerate

New to python and trying to learn the ropes of file i/o.

I am working with pulling lines from a large (2 million line) file in this format:

```
56fr4
4543d
4343d
5irh3
```

Here is the function I'm using to return a code:

```
def getCode(i):
    with open("test.txt") as f:
        for index, line in enumerate(f):
            if index == i:
                code = # what does it equal?
                break
    return code
```

Once the index gets to the right spot (i), what syntax do I use to set the code variable?

Comment: This question has been asked (several times) before (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081836/reading-specific-lines-only-python) and there are some good answers, with discussion; some use enumerate and some linecache (which may be faster). There are also some bad answers, which is itself educational.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`code = line.strip()`

will assign code to the line number that is equal to i while removing the trailing new line.

you also need to update your code a bit

```
 def getCode(i):
    with open('temp.txt', 'r') as f:
             for index, line in enumerate(f):
                     if index == i:
                             code = line.strip()
                             return code
```

**why you need `.strip()`**

```
>>> def getCode(i):
...     with open('temp.txt') as f:
...             for index, line in enumerate(f):
...                     if index == i:
...                             code = line
...                             return code
 ... 
>>> getCode(2)
"                  'LINGUISTIC AFFILIATION',\n"
```

yes, "                   'LINGUISTIC AFFILIATION'," is in my current temp.txt'

Comment: strip() is unnecessary, as only readlines() adds the trailing newline.

Comment: it is in this case. see my updated answer that addresses this.

Comment: the 'return code' should be before the break? I thought return was always supposed to be the last line of a function..?

Comment: well, if you break before returning code, code wont be returned, and if you return code outside of the `if` you run the risk of code never being defined. Try it. I just did before answering. you could define and `else` or a `try` to return the code at the end, but this is perfectly proper.

Comment: You can `return` from anywhere within a function. (Whether you **should** is a bigger argument; try to do things that you can understand easily.) The `break` here is unnecessary, and can never be reached. As soon as a 'return' is encountered, that call of the function stops doing any more work and returns whatever value.

Answer (score 10):

`enumerate` transforms one iterator into another, such that the things you iterate over become pairs of (numeric ID, original item from the underlying iterator).

In our case:

`for index, line in enumerate(f):`

`f` is the file object. File objects are iterators: they iterate over lines of the file.

We transform that into an iterator over (line number, line from file) pairs.

The `for` loop syntax iterates over the iterator, and assigns the (line number, line from file) pair to the variables: (index, line). This is just the normal behaviour of assigning one tuple to another.

So, each time through the loop, `index` gets assigned a line number, and `line` gets assigned the corresponding line from the file. The line from the file is what you want (possibly with some formatting), and `line` contains it, so...

If any of the above didn't make sense, you probably need to re-read an introduction to the language.

Comment: +1 thanks for taking the time to explain `enumerate`  and not just giving him 'what he needs' as I did. or copy a link to the documentation like someone else did. I saw someone earlier answer a question with simply 'sudo' and having it link to wikipedia =(

Comment: I often do answer questions in that terse way, but sometimes it seems clearly necessary to talk people through things.

Comment: I am trying to do basic scripts along the way as I learn.  If I just "read an introduction" it doesn't stick whatsoever, so I try to read a little, then do a small project, and so on.  Is there somewhere on the board that I can ask my easier level questions without people getting annoyed by it?  I read the enumerate documentation several times, but it didn't make sense to me the way it was worded.