# How to add a string to a specific line

Tags: python, linux

I have a file which contains 50 lines. How can i add a string "-----" to a specific line say line 20 using python/linux ?

Comment: split over carriage return (\n) and loop through all lines incrementing a var. every 20 lines, insert whatever string you need. you could also have a regex with 20 carriage return

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried something like this?:

```
exp = 20 # the line where text need to be added or exp that calculates it for ex %2

with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    for i,line in enumerate(lines):
        if i == exp:
            f.write('------')
        f.write(line)
```

If you need to edit diff number of lines you can update code above this way:

```
def update_file(filename, ln):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()

    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        for idx,line in enumerate(lines):
            (idx in ln and f.write('------'))
            f.write(line)
```

Comment: What is `exp`?  I'm assuming you mean 20.

Comment: @squiguy yes) i mean a line where text need to be added

Comment: `exp` is some expression that would match what OP wants.

Comment: Thanks Artsiom it worked for me, but what to do if i have more than 1 line to edit, i.e. i have a list called ln=(3,20,45) which is generated dynamically by the user ?

Comment: @RameshRaithatha (3,20,45) is a lines to be modified?

Answer (score 3):

```
$ head -n 20 input.txt > output.txt
$ echo "---" >> output.txt
$ tail -n 30 input.txt >> output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If the file to read is big, and you don't want to read the whole file in memory at once:

```
from tempfile import mkstemp
from shutil import move
from os import remove, close

line_number = 20

file_path = "myfile.txt"

fh_r = open(file_path)
fh, abs_path = mkstemp()
fh_w = open(abs_path, 'w')

for i, line in enumerate(fh_r):
    if i == line_number - 1:
        fh_w.write('-----' + line)
    else:
        fh_w.write(line)

fh_r.close()
close(fh)
fh_w.close()

remove(file_path)
move(abs_path, file_path)
```

**Note: I used Alok's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081836/reading-specific-lines-only-python) as a reference.**