# How do I access specific lines in a text file

Tags: python

How do I access specific lines (ie #10-#20) in a text file? I tried `for iteration in range(10,20):` but it doesn't work.

Comment: show the code of your iteration and its output

Comment: your question is about line, but you tried to get range! so what is the actual problem?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?#itertools.islice).

```
import itertools

with open('test.txt', 'rt') as file:
    lines = list(itertools.islice(file, 10-1, 20))
```

Whether you should use `10` or `10-1` for the first argument to `islice()` depends on whether you consider the first line of a file line 0, or line 1. Also note that the strings in `lines` will each end with a newline character.

Comment: One of these days I'll get in the habit of using `with` blocks.

Comment: This is actually better than the accepted answer to the duplicate question, although [one of the others](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27108718/355230) says essentially the same thing.

Comment: @martineau Aw, thanks! :) Yeah, I was flipping through the top answers to the dupe, and I was surprised that none of them suggested islice.

Comment: Yes it is, especially since `itertools.islice()` has been around since version Python v2.3.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want

```
f = open('file.txt','r')
all_lines = f.readlines()
required_lines = [all_lines[i] for i in range(10,21)]
```

`required_lines` will now contain lines from line#10 to line#20

Comment: Note that this will read the whole file; for large files, if you only want ten lines, that's somewhat inefficient.