# How to convert generator object into list?

Tags: python, list, generator

My code

```
def yieldlines(thefile, whatlines):
  return (x for i, x in enumerate(thefile) if i in whatlines)

file1=open('/home/milenko/EDIs/site1/newst2.txt','r')
whatlines1 = [line.strip() for line in open('m1.dat', 'r')]

x1=yieldlines(file1, whatlines1)

print x1
```

I got

```
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7fa3cd3d59b0>
```

Where should I put the list,or I need to rewrite the code?

I want my program to pen the file and read the content so for specific lines that are written in m1.dat.I have found that solution 
[Reading specific lines only (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081836/reading-specific-lines-only-python)

Comment: Please explain exactly what you are trying to do. Because what you just got is a [generator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) and there is nothing *really* wrong. If you iterate over it you will get your output. But there are differences you need to be aware of. Make sure you read the link I provided.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If you actually need a list, you can just do:

```
lst = list(generator_object)
```

However, if all you want is to iterate through the object, you do not need a list:

```
for item in generator_object:
    # do something with item
```

For example,

```
sqr = (i**2 for i in xrange(10)) # <generator object <genexpr> at 0x1196acfa0>
list(sqr) # [0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]

sqr = (i**2 for i in xrange(10))
for x in sqr:
    print x,
# 0 1 4 9 16 25 36 49 64 81
```

Comment: No.with print list(x1),I got only [].Why?

Comment: Your generator must be empty. either `thefile` is empty or no line satisfied the condition.

Answer (score 4):

To convert a generator expression into a list it is sufficient to do:

```
list(<generator expression>)
```

Beware though if the generator expression can generate an infinite list, you will not get what you expect.