# Python lambda function to sort list of tuples

Tags: python, sorting, functional-programming

Initially, a list of tuples is sorted by their second value and their third value.

```
tlist = [('a', 1, 14), ('a', 1, 16), ('b', 1, 22), 
        ('a', 2, 1), ('c', 2, 9), ('d', 2, 11), ('d', 2, 12)]
```

Trying to **sort this list of tuples by their second value, reverse by their third value**; that is, want the output of the `list` to be sorted like so:

```
tlist= [('b', 1, 22), ('a', 1, 16), ('a', 1, 14), 
        ('d', 2, 12), ('d', 2, 11), ('c', 2, 9), ('a', 2, 1)]
```

This is what I have tried so far as seen in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36926105/6182051):

```
tlist = sorted(tlist, key=lambda t: return (t[0], t[1], -t[2]))
```

but it does not work; gives a `return outside of function` error.

Any ides of how to get the desired output?

**EDIT**

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121979/how-to-sort-list-tuple-of-lists-tuples) provides very good resources and perhaps all someone would need to go ahead and tackle my specific question. However, given my low level of experience and my specific instance of sorting with different sorting criteria (as described on the description above), I think this is no duplicate.

Comment: A lambda expression does not need a `return` statement.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort (list/tuple) of lists/tuples?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121979/how-to-sort-list-tuple-of-lists-tuples)

Comment: @AKS You have a point for my question having similarity with the question you note; I edited my question to point out why I feel it is not a duplicate due to different sorting criteria.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A [*lambda expression*](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/lambda_functions.hawk) does not use a `return` statement. You should thus drop the `return` keyword.

You also seem to sort first on the first element of the tuples. In order to only take the second element and use descending order of the third element as a tie breaker, you should rewrite the lambda to:

```
lambda t: (t[1],-t[2])
```

Or putting it all together:

```
tlist = sorted(tlist, key=lambda t: (t[1],-t[2]))
```

Running this in `python3` generates:

```
>>> tlist= [('b', 1, 22), ('a', 1, 16), ('a', 1, 14), 
...         ('d', 2, 12), ('d', 2, 11), ('c', 2, 9), ('a', 2, 1)]
>>> tlist = sorted(tlist, key=lambda t: (t[1],-t[2]))
>>> list(tlist)
[('b', 1, 22), ('a', 1, 16), ('a', 1, 14), ('d', 2, 12), ('d', 2, 11), ('c', 2, 9), ('a', 2, 1)]
```

Comment: this is duplicated, why answering?

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel: The second "error" is not a duplicate I think, if you only drop the `return` statement, it will take the first element of the tuple as primary sorting criterium.

Answer (score 2):

This also works and solves the question.

```
>>> sorted(tlist, key=lambda t : (-t[1], t[2]), reverse=True)
```