# A program which will modify another program by using python 3

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to write a program in python which will modify another python program. Steps will be as follows:

1. I have a program `(pyh.py)` which contains below-mentioned lines and output is as follows

output:

```
Number of lines: 6 
Number of characters: 65
```

code for `pyh.py`:

```
import os
import sys

def pyh( filename ):

    if ( os.path.isfile( filename ) ):

        file = open( filename, 'r' )
        line_list = file.readlines()
        pyh_compute_size( line_list )
        file.close()

    else:
        print( "File " + filename + " does not exist." )


def pyh_compute_size( line_list ):

    line_count = 0; char_count = 0
    for line in line_list:

        line_count += 1
        char_count += len( line )

    print( "Number of lines: " + str( line_count ) )
    print( "Number of characters: " + str( char_count ) )


if __name__ == '__main__':

    pyh( "text_a.txt" )
```

2. What I am trying to do is, I am writing another python program called ‘`modifier.py`’ which will open ‘`pyh.py`’ (in the same directory) and read the file then close it.
3. Then open the same file ‘`pyh.py`’ for writing. It will go through the list of line and write line 1 to 20 in the new file (`modifier.py`). After that, it removes the newline from the end of it, and add; `print ("Additional Part"`) to the end, and then add a newline.
4. After that, it will write from 21 to end to the new file (`modifier.py`).

When I run the `‘modifier.py’` it will modify the `‘pyh.py’` (for line between 20 & 21). When `‘pyh.py’` is modified then it should show the below output.

```
Additional Part
Additional Part
Number of lines: 6 
Number of characters: 65
```

I am trying to do the step 3 & 4 but unable to find the appropriate way. I am new in python. So it would be really great if someone helps me to solve it.

code for `modifier.py` is as follow:

```
import os
import sys


def pyh_new( filename ):

    if ( os.path.isfile( filename ) ):

        file = open( filename, 'r' )
        line_list = file.readlines()
        file.close()

def pyh_new( filename ):

    if ( os.path.isfile( filename ) ):

        file = open( filename, 'w' )
        line_list = file.writelines()
        #need to write 

        file.close()



if __name__ == '__main__':

    pyh_new( "pyh.py" )
```

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:python-2.7] if you are specifically looking for [tag:python-3.x] help?

Answer (score 0):

You have pyh_new listed twice.  What you could do is call the name of the first one phy_new_read, and the second one phy_new_write. Then you would want to make phy_new_read return the line_list. `return line_list`. You would then be able to do:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    lines = pyh_new_read( "pyh.py" )

    #grab the specific lines that you want. See 
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081836/reading-specific-lines-only-python

    pyh_new_write( lines )
```

See the following question for how to get specific lines from a file
[Reading specific lines only (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081836/reading-specific-lines-only-python)