# Python: Open a Large Text File, But Load Only Rows Containing a Predefined Column Value

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I am trying to read a very large text file (.dat file) - too large to open in full - but I am not interested in the full content (only a minor part).

The real text file has 32 columns and an unknown number of rows. I am only interested in the rows where the value in column nr 15 is less than 40 and the value in column 21 is between 10 - 25. Is there a way to specify these constraints when opening and loading the file in python so that I avoid wasting memory on the content I don't care about?

Here is an example:

Let's say we have a file of 100 data (25 rows and 4 columns) and we only want to read the rows (the full rows!) where the value in column nr 2 is less than 40 and the value in column nr 4 is between 10 - 25. How can we do this without first loading the full file?

```
import numpy as np
# Create some examplary fake data for the text file:
textfile_content = np.random.randint(100, size=100).reshape(25,4)
print(textfile_content)
# Save text file:
np.savetxt('file.dat', textfile_content, fmt='%10.5e')
```

The closest approach I have been able to google is this: [Reading specific lines only (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081836/reading-specific-lines-only-python)
But it doesn't quite solve my problem, as this person wants to extract full columns, predefined by their column number and not a specific data value.

Comment: I suggest [`dask.dataframe`](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe.html#) to lazily filter. Then bring into memory in `pandas` and output to `numpy` array.

Comment: Okay, thank you @jpp Could you show me an example?

Comment: @jpp I edited the code above to save a tex file as well. Thank you for trying to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`dask.dataframe`](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe.html) to lazily load data with a filter. Internally, this library works by chunking. It just hides the chunking from the user and leverages Pandas syntax to make usage seamless.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import dask.dataframe as dd

# file.csv
# 1 2 3 4
# 5 6 7 8
# ....
# 33 34 35 36
# 37 38 39 40

# read file - LAZY
df = dd.read_csv(r'C:\Temp\file.csv', header=None, sep=' ',
                 names=['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4'])

# filter file - LAZY
df = df[df['col4'].between(10, 25)]

# apply computations and extract to pandas dataframe
df = df.compute()

# extract numpy array from pandas dataframe
arr = df.values

print(arr)

array([[ 9, 10, 11, 12],
       [13, 14, 15, 16],
       [17, 18, 19, 20],
       [21, 22, 23, 24]], dtype=int64)
```