# Creating, then appending data on to the end of each line on a text file in python

Tags: python, database

I am trying to create a database to store the information generated by my code in the form of a 1 x 21 vector. I have called this `prices`, and would like to store each element of this vector in a new line of a text file. Then, the second time I run the program, I wish to append the new entries of the vector `prices` onto each respective line in the text file. The purpose of this is so that once a large set of results has been gathered, it is easy to produce a plot to see how each of these 21 elements changed over time.

I tried to copy (with a bit of modification with the condition in the if loop, as well as the overall for loop) the method shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081836/reading-specific-lines-only), but for some reason, I get a blank text file when I run the code. I changed one thing, the `w` to `w+`, but it doesn't work with the `w` either. What am I doing wrong?

```py
prices = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1] # this is just a sample output
for exp in range(21):
    with open("price_database.txt", 'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()

    with open("price_database.txt", 'w+') as f:
        for x, line in enumerate(lines):
            if x == exp:
                f.write(str(prices[exp]))
            f.write(line)
```

---

Edit 1:

```py
prices = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1]
for exp in range(21):
    with open("price_database.txt", 'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    with open("price_database.txt", 'a') as f:
        for x, line in enumerate(lines):
            if x == exp:
                f.write(str(prices[exp]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to close the file every time you open to read or write  results with f.close() but i cant undertand why you use txt file to do  this job you should really use csv or even mysql it will be much better

Edited:
Open the file with append mode so you can write at the end:

```
with open('something.txt', 'a') as f:
    f.write('text to be appended')
    f.close()
```

Comment: I am quite new to python and asked a friend who did something similar with a text file. I don't really know how to do anything with a csv file, but I will look into this perhaps when I look to improve this. I just tried to add f.close onto the end of each of the `with` loops, but the text file is still empty. If this is much easier with a csv file, and isnt too complicated, would you mind pointing out how I can do it that way?

Comment: Edited and for the future look at csv module so you can structure your data

Comment: If you open the file with "with" operator, you don't need to close explicitly.

Comment: You don't need close the file when you use the `with` statement, because it does it by itself, you can also write a file using `print()` as well, you just need inform the argument `file`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be a little less careful, then do it this way, it is slightly faster because you don’t have to keep closing.

```
app = 'append text'
with open('something.txt', 'a') as f:
    f.write(app)
f.close()
```