# Why can't I read a line from a file and print it?

Tags: python, file, file-writing

I have the following code:

```
test_file = open("test.txt","r")
line1 = test_file.readline(1)
test_file.close()
line1 = int(line1)
print(line1)
```

I have `12` written into the file.

I simply get the output `1`.

Can someone please explain what is wrong with this code?

Comment: `line1 = test_file.readline()`, no need of `1`

Comment: If I had more lines in the file and I only wanted to read the first one, how would I do that?

Comment: @francisco, you are not using any loops so you are just reading the first line

Comment: call `readline` multiple times. Or loop over `test_file.readlines()`, which basically does the same thing internally, call `readline` multiple times (I guess).

Comment: please read the manual for a function if you have a question about a specific function's behaviour. please do this before posting here.

Comment: The parameter to ``readline`` indicates how many characters to read. You literally told it to only read the first character -- i.e. ``1``.

Comment: This question has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081836/reading-specific-lines-only).

Answer (score 2):

The function `readline()` has no parameter for reading a special line. It reads from the file line-by-line for each call. To read just the first line call the function one time like:

```
line1 = test_file.readline()
```

Comment: You can call it in a `for` loop and increment an index. When the index is reached a specific number you have the specific line you want.

Answer (score 1):

You have passed the `size` to read in your code. It read the bytes accordingly to passed size in `readline` method

Also use `with` to open file (in pythonic way)

```
with open("test.txt","r") as test_file:
    line1 = test_file.readline()
    line1 = int(line1)
print(line1)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you specify `1`, you are telling `readline()` to take only the first character in your line, it's better to do this update on your code:

```
test_file = open("test.txt","r")
line1 = test_file.readline() # Remove the indice 1
test_file.close()
line1 = int(line1)
print(line1)
```

Or in one line like this:

```
print(int(open("test.txt","r").readline()))
```