# How to print specific lines of a file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of integers, for example:

```
Mylist = [3, 6, 17, 55]
```

I have a `Myfile.txt` file containing 100s of lines.

Now I have to extract the lines which are present in `Mylist` from `Myfile.txt` and store them in another list.

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: Have you read this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081836/reading-specific-lines-only

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution making use of list comprehension

```py
with open('Myfile.txt','r') as f:
    data = f.read().split('\n')
NewList = [data[x] for x in Mylist]
```

Comment: Downside of this is reading the whole file, even after the last line you actually want. Also you don't call the read method.

Comment: Correct, sorry, updated to fix calling the method. How would you suggest reading specific lines from a file?

Comment: Not specific lines, necessarily, but e.g. using `enumerate(f)` would give you an iterable of tuples `(index, line)` where you could consume only as many as you actually needed. There's an example of that on the dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2081880/3001761