# How to print only certain lines from a .txt file

Tags: python

`1,02/09/15,18:00,RNGesus,Ingsoc,Y,Ingsoc`
`2,03/09/15,18:00,M’lady,Napoleon Wilson,Y,Napoleon Wilson`
`3,04/09/15,18:00,Ripley,Billy Casper,Y,Billy Casper`
`4,05/09/15,18:00,Jenkins,Tyler,Y,Jenkins`

How do I print only the date on the 3rd line?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63868399/4626254 This should work.

Comment: Assuming your text blob is named `alltext`, you get the third line after splitting it into a list of lines: `alltext.split("\n")[2]`

Comment: Read a file line-wise and count the current line. Print the lines you want to print.

Answer (score 2):

This should help you:

```
f = open("D:\\Test.txt","r")
third_line = f.readlines()[2].strip()
f.close()
print(third_line)
```

Output:

```
3,04/09/15,18:00,Ripley,Billy Casper,Y,Billy Casper
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's example:

```
with open("./records.txt") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
        if i==3:
            print(line)
```