# Writing content of a large file to Dynamo from S3 with Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-s3, lambda, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I have multiple large csv files in a S3 bucket. I want to write their data to a dynamoDB table.
The issue is my function runs for more than 15 minutes and get the timeout error without completely writing the csv filevto DynamoDB.
So is there a way to split the csv into smaller parts?

Things I've tried so far

[this](https://medium.com/swlh/processing-large-s3-files-with-aws-lambda-2c5840ae5c91) - This doesn't invoke itself as it is supposed to be(writes a few lines to the table then stops without any errors.
[aws document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/developerguide/tutorials-importing-data-lambda-function-input-split.html) - Gives s3fs module not found error. Tried many many things to make it work but couldn't.

Is there anyway I can do my task?

Thank You

Answer (score 2):

I think the fan-out approach from your linked solution should be the best option.

Take a main lambda function which will split the processing by dividing the number of lines (e.g. 1000 Lines each) into fan-out calls for your processing lambda, which will be invoked with `Event` instead of `Tail`. The processing lambdas should then only read the CSV lines assigned to it (have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081836/reading-specific-lines-only)).

If you already tried this, could you probably post parts of your solution?

Answer (score 1):

I could fix my problem (partly) by increasing the writing capacity on dynamodb to 1000 minimum. I could write 1 million records in 10 minutes. Still I needed to split the csv file. Also using batch_write instead of writing each item line by line helps tremendously.