# How do I read a specific line from a string in Python?

Tags: python, line

How can I read a specific line from a string in Python? For example, let's say I want line 2 of the following string:

```
string = """The quick brown fox 
jumps over the
lazy dog."""
line = getLineFromString(string, 2)
print(line)  # jumps over the
```

There are several questions about [reading specific lines from a file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2081836/3357935), but how would I read specific lines from a string?

Comment: Have you tried splitting the string into a list and using list indexing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no primitives in python, so your string is an object. Which has methods, including [`splitlines()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=splitlines#str.splitlines).

```
my_string = """The quick brown fox 
jumps over the
lazy dog."""

line = my_string.splitlines()[1]   # 0 based index, so 1 is the second line

print(line)  # 'jumps over the'
```

Answer (score -1):

You can split the string on the newlines, then take the Nth element of the resulting array.

```py
string.split('\n')
# => ['The quick brown fox ', 'jumps over the', 'lazy dog.']
```

Remember that Python arrays are 0-indexed, so the 2nd element is at index `1`.

```py
string.split('\n')[1]
# => 'jumps over the'
```

Comment: This will go wrong if the line break is something else, such as on widows. `splitlines()` takes care of all that.

Comment: @MatBailie's answer is better in general. Please use that unless you specifically need to split on a particular character.