# How to read one particular line from .txt file in python?

Tags: python

I know I can read the line by line with

```
dataFile = open('myfile.txt', 'r')
firstLine = dataFile.readline()
secondLine = dataFile.readline()
...
```

I also know how to read all the lines in one go

```
dataFile = open('myfile.txt', 'r')
allLines =  dataFile.read()
```

But my question is **how to read one particular line from `.txt` file?**

I wish to read that line by its index.

e.g. I want the 4th line, I expect something like

```
dataFile = open('myfile.txt', 'r')
allLines =  dataFile.readLineByIndex(3)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Skip 3 lines:

```
with open('myfile.txt', 'r') as dataFile:
    for i in range(3):
        next(dataFile)
    the_4th_line = next(dataFile)
```

Or use [`linecache.getline`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/linecache.html#linecache.getline):

```
the_4th_line = linecache.getline('myfile.txt', 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

From another [Ans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444538/go-to-a-specific-line-in-python?answertab=votes#tab-top)

```
Use Python Standard Library's linecache module:

line = linecache.getline(thefilename, 33)
should do exactly what you want. You don't even need to open the file -- linecache does it all for you!
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do exactly as you wanted with this:

```
DataFile = open('mytext.txt', 'r')

content = DataFile.readlines()

oneline = content[5]

DataFile.close()
```

you could take this down to three lines by removing `oneline = content[5]` and using `content[5]` without creating another variable (`print(content[5])` for example) I did this just to make it clear that `content[5]` **must** be a used as a list to read the one line.