# Python CSV reader start at line_num

Tags: python, csv

I need to read a CSV with a couple million rows.  The file grows throughout the day.  After each time I process the file (and zip each row into a dict), I start the process over again, except creating the dict only for the new lines.

In order to get to the new lines though, I have to iterate over each line with CSV reader and compare the line number to my 'last line read' number (as far as I know).

Is there a way to just 'skip' to that line number?

Answer (score 2):

You can't go to a specific line number, unless the size of a line is fixed and you know this size. When I say you can't, I mean you can't without loading the whole file in memory and split by `\n` character.

If your CSV has a fixed-line size like this:

```
id,code,quantity
0001,ABC43,00100
0002,D2ZAD,00020
....
```

where each line has the same length, then you could move to `linesize*(linenumber+1)`, where `linenumber` is the line you want to go.
Otherwise, you need to loop through the whole file to get the `n`-th line... It exists a built-in module, name [`linecache`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/linecache.html?highlight=linecache#module-linecache) which can help you however: [Go to a specific line in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444538/go-to-a-specific-line-in-python)

Comment: Thank you very much for this helpful response.  I will try linecache this afternoon.

Comment: I'm a little curious as to how to proceed once I use linecache to get to the specific line.

Comment: I don't really know how works `linecache` internally. You could iterate your every line by getting `linecache.getline(filename, n)` with `n` from `linenumber`, and stops when it returns an empty string (means the line doesn't exists according to the doc). 
Check performance, but the doc says that `linecache` manage an internal cache, so it should be fine.

Comment: I'm imagining a use for linecache where I could instruct it to grab all lines from a specific line to the end of the file (or a fixed number of lines, say, 20,000 at a time).  If linecache can only grab one line at a time, I think it won't lead to an easy or elegant solution.  I am going to continue researching obviously... Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

If I were doing this I think I would add a marker line after each read - before the file is saved again , then I would read the file in as a string , split on the marker, convert back to a list and feed the list to the process.