# getting TypeError in file but correct answer in shell

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io

My code is as follows:

```
def randword():
    #american-english-small can be replaced with american-english[-large|-huge]
    DICT = open('/usr/share/dict/american-english-small', 'r')
    length = len(DICT.readlines())
    print(length)
    randline = randint(1, length)
    print(randline) 
    word = DICT.readline(randline)
    print(word)
    DICT.close()
    return word
    #return DICT.readline(randint(1, len(DICT.readlines())))
```

The one-liner at the end is my original code, the rest is me taking it apart to find the problem. In my terminal, it all comes out correct:

```
>>> DICT = open('/usr/share/dict/american-english-small', 'r')
>>> word = DICT.readline(46957)
>>> print(word)
AIDS's
```

However, when I run my file, there's an error between finding the line and reading the line:

```
51175
18132
```

The traceback on the runtime error:

```
 +---+
 |   |
 O   |
/|\  |
/ \  |
     |
==========

Incorrect guesses: a b c d e f 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/joshua/Documents/Coding/Python/hangman.py", line 123, in     <module>
    main()
  File "/home/joshua/Documents/Coding/Python/hangman.py", line 117, in main
    "\nThe word was " + secretWord + ".")
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error would be helpful... Also, what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga added. I'm trying to choose a random word from a dictionary file. Each word is on it's own line like such: `a\n an\n animal\n`

Comment: The error message you're showing us has nothing to do with the code you posted.

Comment: Well, firstly, `readline(46957)` isn't doing what you think it's doing. It's reading *the next line* and setting an upper limit to the byte size, not reading the 46957th line. Second, the error you are showing is just saying that `secretWord` is an `int`, and you are trying to add it with `+` to a string, which isn't allowed. Finally, since you already did `readlines()` you've exhauseted the file, and `readline` will return and empty string: `''`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Oh, I see. How do I read the 46957th line, in that case? thanks for the help.

Comment: @user2357112 `secretWord` is just the variable name I used in the rest of my code for `word`. I didn't copy the whole page and a half because the rest is working fine.

Comment: @JoshuaNelson: The rest is *not* working fine. While the code you've shown us is wrong (as juanpa points out), it's wrong in a way that has nothing to do with the error message.

Comment: @JoshuaNelson to get to a specific line, you either have to iterate the number of lines,  or use some other utility. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444538/go-to-a-specific-line-in-python). The accepted answer suggests using [linecache](https://docs.python.org/3/library/linecache.html#module-linecache).

Comment: The problematic variable might not be `secretWord`. Python stack traces will always point to the last physical line of a logical line involved in the stack trace, even if the problem is on a different physical line. Check for other things that could be `int`s that you're trying to add to strings.

Comment: @user2357112 the closest I have is `errors += guess`; changing that to `errors.append(guess)` didn't change anything. I never redefined `secretWord` after I initialized it.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga using linecache fixed my problem right up. I broke some other things messing around with this, but the file I/O is working great now. Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: @user2357112 arrghh i feel like an idiot. You were absolutely right, there was a line before that was part of the same print statement, I forgot to convert a len() to a string.

Comment: In future questions, please read [ask] and especially [mcve] before posting. Then ensure that your question includes a program that is short, complete, and allows others to reproduce your error.

Comment: @Robᵩ will do. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the traceback, `secretWord` is an integer not a string:

```
"\nThe word was " + secretWord + ".")
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
```

Without seeing your other code where you assign `secretWord`, my guess is that `secretWord` is the index to a list or a dictionary and that you should instead be doing something like

```
"\n`enter code here`The word was " + wordcontainer[secretWord] + "."
```

where wordcontainer is a list or dictionary of words.

**Edit**

It's also possible that you just happened to randomly draw a page number or something like that which is part of your document and so when you read the line in from the document it gets read in as an integer. In that case, you would either need to handle that possibility or you might consider using a prexisting list of words that is already in a nice Python format.

```
from nltk.corpus import words #You will need to use nltk.download() to download this in addition to using pip to install the package.
wordlist = words.words()
```

Comment: Right, but I have no idea why. The code is `secretWord = randword()` and there's no reason I see that randword() should evaluate to an integer.

Comment: Well, try printing the `secretWord` object just before that line and see what happens. `print(type(secretWord), secretWord)`

Comment: Scratch that. I copied `print(type(secretWord))` and for some reason it came out to `<class 'str'>`. I'm still getting the TypeError, though, somehow it's changing to an integer between there and the end of the loop. Thanks for the leads.

Comment: You need to put the print line just after you define `secretWord`, otherwise you have not defined it and it has no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: So to debug then put the same print statement throughout the script and see where it changes. You might also consider just using a preexisting corpus (see my answer).

Answer (score 0):

I'm a fool - I had multiple lines as part of the same statement, but the traceback only return the last line. @user2357112 figured it out way before me.
My code before I fixed it:

```
            print("You've run out of guesses. \nYou had " + len(errors) +
              " errors and " + len(correctGuesses) + " correct guesses. " +
              "\nThe word was " + secretWord + ".")
```

and after:

```
            print("You've run out of guesses. \nYou had " + str(len(errors)) +
              " errors and " + str(len(correctGuesses)) + " correct guesses. " +
              "\nThe word was " + secretWord + ".")
```

Shoutout to @juanpa.arrivillaga for fixing the probem I thought I had; I switched `readline(n)` to `linecahce.getline(n)` which cleared my input problem right up.