# How to get the text from a specific line of text?

Tags: python

How can I take text file and access/return a specific line from the file? 
For example, "File.txt" is 100 lines long and I want the information that's contained on lines 1,31,61 and 91.

```
dataFile = open("File.text","a+")
```

Comment: What did you try so far? Please include your code in the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Go to a specific line in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444538/go-to-a-specific-line-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

```
def get_lines(filename, line_numbers):
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line_number, line in enumerate(f):
            if line_number in line_numbers:
                yield line_number, line


for line_number, line in get_lines('tmp.txt', (1, 3)):
    print(line_number, line)
```

This code returns a generator iterator so you should loop through it.