# How to iterate two files with different steps without loading them all in memory using python?

Tags: python, algorithm

Let's say I have two files A and B

in A I have 100 lines, in B I have 10 lines, I need to do an operation on every 10 lines in A and every 1 line in B.

for example in A, I have following lines
a1
a2
...
a10
a11
..
a20
...
a100

in B I have following lines:
b1
b2
...
b10

I would like to do an operation on data a1,a2..a10 and b1, and I would like to do the operation again on data a11, a12... a20 and b2.

So the problem is both A and B are very huge, I cannot load them all in memory, so I need to iterate them line by line, but with different speed because 10 lines in A map to 1 line in B. How to do that without preprocessing A to make it with same row size with B?

(I use python 2.7)

Comment: It looks like this might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444538/go-to-a-specific-line-in-python

Comment: @Peiti - did you try my solution? If it worked then please accept the answer and vote up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a common idiom to iterate over "chunks" using `itertools.izip` and an unpacked list of references to a single iterator:

```
from itertools import izip

for values in izip(*[iter]*n): # values will hold n values at a time
```

For your purpose, you can add a reference to your smaller file along with multiple references to the larger file (files are iterators):

```
with open("A") as file_a, open("B") as file_b:
    for values in izip(file_b, *[file_a]*10): # values will have one B value and 10 A values
        # do stuff here with the values
```

If the files might not line up exactly, you can use `itertools.izip_longest` instead of the regular `izip`. It will let you supply a default value to use if the inputs don't match up exactly right. In Python 3, the regular builtin `zip` works like `itertools.izip` does in Python 2, so you wouldn't need to import anything.

Comment: This is a beautiful solution *for Python 3.X*. The unpacking syntax in the `for` loop is not in Python 2.7 (which the OP is using). You'd have to update to be something like `for all_values in ... b_values, a_values = all_values[0], all_values[1:]`

Comment: Oh, that's right. My initial solution was all Python 3 (using the normal `zip`) and I thought I'd back-ported everything, but I guess not. Well, you can get the whole set of values in a single tuple I guess and manually unpack later.

Answer (score 1):

The standard `file.readline` method will give you your single line reads.  Opening a file object does not load them into memory all at once; the files are buffered and the file position advanced as subsequent readlines are called.  In this manner, you could accomplish what you are looking for like so:

```
def process(a_data, b_data):
    pass  # Your code here

a_data = [None] * 10
with open('pathToFileB', 'r') as fileB:
    with open('pathToFileA', 'r') as fileA:
        for b_data in fileB:
            for i in len(a_data):
                a_data[i] = a.readline()
            process(a_data, b_data)
```

Of course, this assumes that file A is assured to have 10 lines for every line in file B; when it reaches the end of file A, if there are still lines left in file B, `a_data` will be filled with `None` values.

Answer (score 1):

You can write some generic code that can print lines from files `a.txt` and `b.txt` depending on how many lines they have.

You can either derive it dynamically as below or even hard-code the interval (`factor=10`) in below code.

`NOTE`: For my sample execution, `a.txt` has a1..a33 (33 lines) and `b.txt` has b1..b3 (3 lines)

```
import math

## capture all data from files into a list    
alines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('a.txt')]
blines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('b.txt')]

## you can have your own custom factor too
## e.g. 10 as you explain in question
factor = math.ceil(len(alines) / len(blines))
print("Your factor is: " + str(factor))
print("\n")

acount = 0
bcount = 0

## iterate thru all elements of a and b file
for line in range(len(alines) + len(blines)):
    ## print b only when its turn
    if (bcount < len(blines) and (line % (factor+1)) == 0):
        print(blines[bcount])
        bcount = bcount + 1
    else:
        ## print a when its turn
        if (acount < len(alines)):
            print(alines[acount])
            acount = acount + 1
```

Sample Run

```
b1
a1
a2
a3
a4
a5
a6
a7
a8
a9
a10
a11
b2
a12
a13
a14
a15
a16
a17
a18
a19
a20
a21
a22
b3
a23
a24
a25
a26
a27
a28
a29
a30
a31
a32
a33
```