# Edit a line in json lines / nd json

Tags: python, json

I'm using [Jsonlines](http://jsonlines.org/) aka [ndjson](http://ndjson.org/), and want to edit a single key/value in a single line using python and update the line in the file.

Currently, the python libraries [jsonlines](https://pypi.org/project/jsonlines/) and [json-lines](https://pypi.org/project/json-lines/) seem only to allow you to read existing entries or write new entries but not edit existing entries.

For example, in the [jsonlines library](https://jsonlines.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), you can open the file and wrap the objects in reader or writer :

```py
import jsonlines
with jsonlines.open('input.jsonl') as reader:
    for obj in reader:
        ...

with jsonlines.open('output.jsonl', mode='w') as writer:
    writer.write(...)
```

Say you have the following jsonlines file :

```
{"name":"Alice","age":24}
{"name":"Bob","age":22}
```

Updating a dictionary in python is fairly easy.  In this case, it would be something like :

```
entry = {"name":"Alice","age":24}
entry.update({"age":25})
```

And the library seems to open the lines as dictionaries.  And you can call the update method from within the jsonlines library :

```py
import jsonlines
with open('names.jsonl', 'rb') as f:
    for item in json_lines.reader(f):
        item.update({'age':25})
        print(item['age'])
```

This has two problems :

- it will not actually update the file ... just the dictionary temporarily

  - the file `names.jsonl` remains unchanged
- it will do this for all the entries and not just a specific entry / line

  - this is of course because opened within a loop
  - you can go to a specific line via line number based on [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2444559)
  - but it presumes you know the specific line number
  - when really you **just want to find Alice by name and update her age in that entry**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code:

```
import jsonlines


with jsonlines.open('input.jsonl') as reader, jsonlines.open('output.jsonl', mode='w') as writer:
    for obj in reader:
        if obj['name'] == 'Alice':
            obj['age'] = 25
        writer.write(obj)
```

It will copy all lines of `input.jsonl` to `output.jsonl` and change the `age` field to `25` when the `name` field is `Alice`

Comment: Thanks!  It works and is an elegant solution!  I did not realize you could open in two modes with comma separation.  It is just unfortunate a separate file has to be created.  But that might be a safer way to go about it.

Comment: you can open in rw mode but you need to seek() back to the wanted position.

Comment: if you are opening from within the jsonlines library, it seems you are strictly limited to 'r','w','a'.  you cannot use any + modes (e.g. 'r+').  any deviation and you unfortunately get this error : `ValueError: 'mode' must be either 'r', 'w', or 'a'`