# linecache.getline() / getlines() does not actually work on a .txt file?

Tags: python

I wanted to get multiple lines from a .txt file, and I read so many [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444538/go-to-a-specific-line-in-python) about "using `linecache.getline` or `getlines`" to retieve certain lines from a .txt file, but when I tried, it just returns empty string, I think I had the correct file path and line number.

In the [document of linecache](https://docs.python.org/3/library/linecache.html#module-linecache) it states that linecache is used to "Cache lines from Python source files". And the example it gives does work

```
import linecache

linecache.getline(linecache.__file__, 8)
```

What I did:

```
import linecache

path = "demo.txt"

line = linecache.getline(path, 19)
print(repr(line))

# output: ''
```

So my question is: `linecache.getline` works with imported .py files because those are cached when being imported, .txt is not cached so it return ''? Then how come others can use it on .txt files ?, is it because the answer I read is a long time ago and it used to work on .txt file?

Hope to get an answer, thx

Comment: It works, but your path is relative and will be resolved from the current working directory. Is the "demo.txt" next to executing script?

Comment: Does demo.txt exist in your current working directory? Does it have at least 19 lines? Note that linecache does not distinguish between a missing/inaccessible file and an invalid line number.

Comment: @ivvija I used absolute path of the .txt file in my local scripts

Comment: @DarkKnight I used absolute path of the .txt file in my local scripts, yes the .txt has at least 19 lines

Comment: @AlexandarZeng The code you show in your question is using a relative pathname for the file. Its location would be relative to your current working directory. If the output is an empty string then either the file cannot be found or the line number you've chosen is a blank line or there are fewer than 19 lines in the file. Note that the line numbers used by linecache are base 1 rather than base 0

Comment: @DarkKnight Thanks for the advice, I change the encoding of the text file from ANSI to utf-8 and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should still work. The text file does not need to contain Python code.

You can check that you have the file in the right place with:

```py
import os
print(os.listdir())
```

I trust you have opened the file with a text editor to see that it does have at least 19 lines. Note that line numbering starts at 1, not 0.

What is the encoding of the file? If it is not UTF-8, that might cause problems.

What happens if you try to read the file in another way? E.g.

```py
with open(path) as f:
    print(f.readlines()[18])
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I try not to use `f.readlines` to avoid reading the whole text file into memory, that's why I wanted to try `linecache.getline`, but I don't really know if it's better than just reading the whole text into memory with `f.readlines`. The encoding of the file is ANSI, do you think it could be reason why this doesn't work?

Comment: I made a new demo.txt with utf-8 encoding and it works.