# Get Line Number of certain phrase in text file

Tags: python, file

I need to get the line number of a phrase in a text file. The phrase could be:

```
the dog barked
```

I need to open the file, search it for that phrase and print the line number.

I'm using Python 2.6 on Windows XP

---

**This Is What I Have:**

```
o = open("C:/file.txt")
j = o.read()
if "the dog barked" in j:
     print "Found It"
else:
     print "Couldn't Find It"
```

This is not homework, it is part of a project I am working on. I don't even have a clue how to get the line number.

Comment: what do you have so far? I mean, we know you know how to open a file. How are you searching for the phrase?

Comment: @SilentGhost, I am a very strong Python programmer. Just never had to do this before. I have written several applications, specifically a web parental controls application that the company will release within the next few months. Just hit a "dead brain cell", thats all.

Answer (score 133, accepted):

```
lookup = 'the dog barked'

with open(filename) as myFile:
    for num, line in enumerate(myFile, 1):
        if lookup in line:
            print 'found at line:', num
```

Comment: Thank you for posting *the right way(tm)* to do it (well, except that line counting starts at 0 - ok for programmers but propably not for non-techies). +1

Comment: This is what worked. Now, just a question... do you know how to read a specific line number in a text file?

Comment: In python 2.6 and later, I think, `enumerate()` takes an argument of the number to start counting at, e.g. `enumerate(myFile, 1)`.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I edited it for python 2.6 (print) and the line starting at 1.

Comment: You can check this post for the opening the file at a specific line: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/620367/python-how-to-jump-to-a-particular-line-in-a-huge-text-file

Answer (score 13):

```
f = open('some_file.txt','r')
line_num = 0
search_phrase = "the dog barked"
for line in f.readlines():
    line_num += 1
    if line.find(search_phrase) >= 0:
        print line_num
```

EDIT 1.5 years later (after seeing it get another upvote): I'm leaving this as is; but if I was writing today would write something closer to Ash/suzanshakya's solution:

```
def line_num_for_phrase_in_file(phrase='the dog barked', filename='file.txt')
    with open(filename,'r') as f:
        for (i, line) in enumerate(f):
            if phrase in line:
                return i
    return -1
```

- Using `with` to open files is the pythonic idiom -- it ensures the file will be properly closed when the block using the file ends.
- Iterating through a file using `for line in f` is much better than `for line in f.readlines()`.   The former is pythonic (e.g., would work if `f` is any generic iterable; not necessarily a file object that implements `readlines`), and more efficient `f.readlines()` creates an list with the entire file in memory and then iterates through it.   * `if search_phrase in line` is more pythonic than `if line.find(search_phrase) >= 0`, as it doesn't require `line` to implement `find`, reads more easily to see what's intended, and isn't easily screwed up (e.g., `if line.find(search_phrase)` and `if line.find(search_phrase) > 0` both will not work for all cases as find returns the index of the first match or -1).
- Its simpler/cleaner to wrap an iterated item in `enumerate` like `for i, line in enumerate(f)` than to initialize `line_num = 0` before the loop and then manually increment in the loop.  (Though arguably, this is more difficult to read for people unfamiliar with `enumerate`.)

See [code like pythonista](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html)

Comment: This is similar to Santiago's solution; except it should be >= 0, as if its at the beginning of the line, find will return 0 if the phrase is present.  (If its not there it will be -1).

Comment: -1 to get it back to 0. Using readlines is rarely a good idea, just iterate the file.

Comment: In the function line_num_for_phrase_in_file, is it IF PHRASE IN F, or IF PHRASE IN LINE?

Answer (score 7):

```
def get_line_number(phrase, file_name):
    with open(file_name) as f:
        for i, line in enumerate(f, 1):
            if phrase in line:
                return i

print get_line_number("the dog barked", "C:/file.txt")  # python2

#print(get_line_number("the dog barked", "C:/file.txt"))  # python3
```

Comment: I would use `return None` rather than `return 0` but this is good.

Comment: I used `return 0` to make the return type of `get_line_number` integer. Why do you think `return None` is better ?

Comment: `None` makes it clear that the phrase wasn't found, while `0` is just a convention. Also it ensures that if the result isn't checked by the caller, the program will likely fail in a spectacular way when the bug is tripped, making debugging easier.

Comment: Thanks Mark for the explanation.

Answer (score 3):

[suzanshakya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/77868/suzanshakya), I'm actually modifying your code, I think this will simplify the code, but make sure before running the code the file must be in the same directory of the console otherwise you'll get error.

```
lookup="The_String_You're_Searching"
file_name = open("file.txt")
for num, line in enumerate(file_name,1):
        if lookup in line:
            print(num)
```

Answer (score 1):

Open your file, and then do something like...

```
for line in f:
    nlines += 1
    if (line.find(phrase) >= 0):
        print "Its here.", nlines
```

There are numerous ways of reading lines from files in Python, but the `for line in f` technique is more efficient than most.

Comment: Wrong? Where? ...? If it's the > instead of >=, I just fixed it, you are right, and ... you could've just pointed that out instead of saying the answer was wrong and embarrasing.

Comment: @santi: embarrassment was writing c code in python. See Sacha's answer

Comment: Yeah, I was unable to get it working. Thanks for posting though.

Comment: @silent come oooon, the question wasn't "what's the most pythonesque way of finding a string in file", maan. Zachary seemed to know little about python, so I wrote a more language-agnostic answer. He is right, tough, Zach: for a better-looking solution, see Sacha's.

Comment: @mark: of course it's not wrong! *any more*. Santiago seems to have a thing for parentheses.

Comment: @Santiago: on opposite! OP says he's a *very strong Python programmer*

Comment: They can hear you guys, they are a few lines above these comments. Leave my parentheses alone. They have feelings, you know.

Comment: What was Sacha's answer? It seems to have been removed.

Answer (score 1):

```
listStr = open("file_name","mode")

if "search element" in listStr:
    print listStr.index("search element")  # This will gives you the line number
```

Comment: This returns the character number instead of line number.

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension:

```py
content = open("path/to/file.txt").readlines()

lookup = 'the dog barked'

lines = [line_num for line_num, line_content in enumerate(content) if lookup in line_content]

print(lines)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for n,line in enumerate(open("file")):
    if "pattern" in line: print n+1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I've found to work:

```
f_rd = open(path, 'r')
file_lines = f_rd.readlines()
f_rd.close()

matches = [line for line in file_lines if "chars of Interest" in line]
index = file_lines.index(matches[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

It's been a solid while since this was posted, but here's a nifty one-liner. Probably not worth the headache, but just for fun :)

```
from functools import reduce 
from pathlib import Path

my_lines       = Path('path_to_file').read_text().splitlines()       
found, linenum = reduce(lambda a, b: a if a[0] else (True, a[1]) if testid in b else (False, a[1]+1), [(False,0)] + my_lines)
            
print(my_lines[linenum]) if found else print(f"Couldn't find {my_str}")
```

Note that if there are two instances in the file, it wil

Answer (score 0):

An one-liner solution:

```py
l_num = open(file).read()[:open(file).read().index(phrase)].count('\n') + 1
```

and an IO safer version:

```py
l_num = (h.close() or ((f := open(file, 'r', encoding='utf-8')).read()[:(f.close() or (g := open(file, 'r', encoding='utf-8')).read().index(g.close() or phrase))].count('\n'))) if phrase in (h := open(file, 'r', encoding='utf-8')).read() else None
```

---

Explain:

```py
file = 'file.txt'
phrase = 'search phrase'
with open(file, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    text = f.read()
    if phrase in text:
        phrase_index = text.index(phrase)
        l_num = text[:phrase_index].count('\n') + 1  # Nth line has n-1 '\n's before
    else:
        l_num = None
```