# Python3: Finding a phrase (string) in a file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a bit confused and hoping you can help....

My overall task is to determine whether a .txt file contains the line `'**** Optimisation achieved ****'`. If it does, make opt = 'Y'. Otherwise don't do anything other than close the file.

I have looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961265/get-line-number-of-certain-phrase-in-file-python), but am having a little trouble with some of the answers:
I define the function `test()` such that when it is called I pass the phrase to be searched for and the filename to it. Within `test()` I open the file and number the lines in it.

```
def test(phrase, filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
         for num, line in enumerate (f,1):
```

it is at this point that I am having issues and am a little confused. The following is based on the answer given by @Dr jimbob and uses `if phrase in f:`, and returns `N`:

```
            if phrase in f:
                return 'Y'
            else:
                return 'N'

opt = test('****Optimisation achieved ****', file.txt)
print(opt)
```

**[N.B. The same occurs if I skip the line in which the lines of the file are numbered]**

However, if I use the following which is based on the answer given by @suzanshakya and uses `if phrase in line:` and returns `Y`:

```
            if phrase in line:
                return 'Y'
            else:
                return 'N'

opt = test('****Optimisation achieved ****', file.txt)
print(opt)
```

I have used the same .txt file for both, and it definitely contains the line `****Optimisation achieved****`.

As the first is more akin to what I want to do, any prods in the right direction would be gratefully received - although I ask patience as my programming is quite basic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not need *line numbers*, you do not need to use enumerate().

This function will read the entire file into `text` then *search through* `text` to see if `phrase` is in it.

```
def test(phrase, filename):
    phrase = phrase.strip()
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        text = f.read()
    if phrase in text:
        return 'Y'
    else:
        return 'N'
```

This function reads the file line by line (iterates over the file) and returns 'Y' if it finds `phrase` in a line.  If it reaches the end of the file, it returns 'N'.

```
def test(phrase, filename):
    phrase = phrase.strip()
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            if phrase in line:
                return 'Y'
        return 'N'
```

Either will work.

- The first may have a speed advantage because it only accesses the file once and searching for the phrase is done in memory.
- The second has the advantage of keeping the memory *footprint* small.

Comment: Make sure you aren't comparing two strings, one with trailing whitespace (`\r\n`) and the other without.

Comment: Your second solution is best, but as @IceArdor mentioned, you should be sure to do `if phrase in line.strip()` instead.

Comment: hmmm, I guess if ```phrase``` somehow had trailing whitespace it would fail but ```phrase in text``` or ```phrase in line``` should work as long as ```phrase``` is actually in ```line``` or ```text```.   Edited to account for possible whitespace in phrase.

Comment: @wwii that's true, my mistake. Most of the matching I do is `if line.strip() == phrase` as I'm looking for an exact line. Good work!