# Get the index of a non-alphanumeric-string in a list containing non-alphanumeric elements in python

Tags: python, list, indexing, non-alphanumeric

I have a file (test.txt) like this:

```
[06/Oct/2017:20:18:47 +0200] [pool-2-thread-7] http://10.12.214.20
[06/Oct/2017:20:19:38 +0200] [pool-2-thread-4] http://10.12.214.18
[06/Oct/2017:20:19:38 +0200] [pool-2-thread-4] http://10.12.214.18
[06/Oct/2017:20:19:49 +0200] [pool-2-thread-8] http://10.12.214.18
[06/Oct/2017:20:19:59 +0200] [pool-2-thread-7] ends.
[06/Oct/2017:20:20:47 +0200] [pool-2-thread-7] http://10.12.214.20
[06/Oct/2017:20:21:24 +0200] [pool-2-thread-4] ends.
[06/Oct/2017:20:21:34 +0200] [pool-2-thread-8] ends.
```

As a python-beginner i wanted to get the linenumber of a specific line, so i searched for a solution and found this post:
[Finding the index of an item given a list containing it in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176918/finding-the-index-of-an-item-given-a-list-containing-it-in-python).
I am using the answer of @tanzil, because later on it is possible, that i do look for elements not in the list.

This is what i do:

Save the lines of the original file in a list:

```
with open(test.txt) as f:
    content = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in f]
    print len(content)
index = [x for x in range(len(content))]
```

Iterate through the original file:

```
with open(test.txt, "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        print find_element_in_list(index, line.rstrip('\n'))
```

Find the index of each line of the original file:

```
def find_element_in_list(index_list, list_element):
    try:
        index_element = index_list.index(list_element)
        return index_element
    except ValueError:
        return None
```

As a result, there is no match at all.
I only get "None" as output.

I read this post ['is' operator behaves differently when comparing strings with spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16756699/is-operator-behaves-differently-when-comparing-strings-with-spaces) and hoped to get an answer to my question, but couldn't adapt the answers to my problem.

I would apreciate any hints or ideas!

(This is not a dublicate of [Get Line Number of certain phrase in file Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961265/get-line-number-of-certain-phrase-in-file-python) because i need to access the indices of different lines multiple times. I am not iterating through the file everytime i need a specific one.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Line Number of certain phrase in file Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961265/get-line-number-of-certain-phrase-in-file-python)

Comment: @sunjazz Try printing the exception. It will help you debug the problem.

Comment: @akhilsp i did, but i got some error, saying that "[06/Oct/2017:20:18:47 +0200] [pool-2-thread-7] http://10.12.214.20" is not an element of the list. Your answer is working fine!

Comment: Glad to know that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking in the wrong list. Instead of looking in the `index`, try looking in `content`

```
with open('test.txt', "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        print find_element_in_list(content, line.rstrip('\n'))
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the line number, you can try this:

```
file = open('filename.txt')
data = file.readlines()
target = "[06/Oct/2017:20:19:49 +0200] [pool-2-thread-8] http://10.12.214.18"
for i, item in enumerate(data, start=1):
    if item == target:
        print('Target is in line: ', str(i))
```

Comment: tried your solution, but its still printing out None.
I do need the loop over the file later on, so i nested the "target" and "the_index" into the for loop like this:
    
    content = [i.strip('\n') for i in open(testfile)]
    with open(testfile) as f:
        for line in f:
            target = line
            index = [i for i,a in enumerate(content) if a == target]
            index = None if not index else index[0]
            print index

Comment: @sunjazz I approved the edit, however, the previous solution worked for me when I tested it. Did you use a different target string?

Comment: Change enumerate's argument "start" to 0 (zero).