# how do i find the index of all occurrences of certain string and store it into list

Tags: python

I have a list/array called `position[]` and it is used to store the position line number of the string by using `find()`. The string is the abc.py which is a python file(I will include the abc.py below).

**Question**: how do find the string position of all `def`.

**Objective**: capture the line number of the first `def` and the second `def` and third etc and stored it in `position[]`

abc.py:

```
 #!C:\Python\Python39\python.exe
    # print ('Content-type: text/html\n\n')

def hello_step0():
    create()
    login()

def hello2_step1():
    delete()

def hello2_step2():
    delete()
```

What i did to find the first occurrence of `def`

```
position = [] 
with open("abc.py","r") as file:
    line = file.readlines()
    line = str(line)
    print(line.strip().find("def")) # output 102
    position.append(line.strip().find("def"))
```

Comment: I think you meant ```line number``` and not ```index``` of ```def``` ?

Comment: yes i mean line number i will edit the word. thanks for the input.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get Line Number of certain phrase in file Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961265/get-line-number-of-certain-phrase-in-file-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`str.startswith`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith):

```py
position = [] 

with open("abc.py") as f:
    for index, line in enumerate(f.readlines()):
        if line.strip().startswith('def'):
            position.append(index)

print(position) #[3, 7, 10] --> line starts with 0

# 0 --> #!C:\Python\Python39\python.exe
# 1--->    # print ('Content-type: text/html\n\n')
# 2-->
# 3-->def hello_step0():
#     create()
```

To start with 1, just replace:

```py
for index, line in enumerate(f.readlines(), 1):
```

Comment: You can just pass `f` to `enumerate`. No need to create a list of `f.readlines()`

Answer (score 1):

The Below code will give append line numbers of lines that starts with `def` to `position` list.

```
position = []
with open('abc.py', 'r') as f:
    for i, val in enumerate(f.readlines()):
        if val.startswith('def'):
            position.append(i)
```

```
Output:

position = [3,7,10]
```