# Copy each line 3 lines previous to each match

Tags: python, python-2.7, matching, sliding-window

I am trying to copy lines four lines before a line that contains a specific keyword.

```
if line.find("keyword") == 0:
    f.write(line -3)
```

I don't need the line where I found the keyword, but 4 lines before it. Since the write method doesn't work with line numbers, I got stuck

Comment: You are aware that writing in place (assuming that `f` is being iterated over line-by-line) will start overwriting already existing data after the found line, right? If so, just keep a `list` with lines while iterating over them and once a `keyword` is found just write the collected list of lines to the file.

Comment: How big is your file?

Comment: @merlin2011 3847 kb ; zwer I have used 2 files, one for reading, another for the writing

Comment: if you don't want to load all the file for any reason, you can have a 4 element list and use `push()` and `pop()` methods like a buffer

Comment: When you say "copy a line" and use `f.write()` (is `f` pointing to the input file or a different file? you need to show the definition of `f`). Are you trying to output a new (summary) file, overwrite the original file, or just get a list in memory of lines 3 lines before matches?

Comment: This is called a ***sliding-window*** or ***rolling buffer***

Comment: Related solution, using deque [How can I print second and last three lines...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11065216/202229). Sadly that question asks for solutions in both AWK and Python, so it's pretty confused.

Comment: Just to point out that if you [**process the file backwards**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301789/read-a-file-in-reverse-order-using-python), you can do all this one shot (assuming you're not trying to overwrite the file).

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a list, append to the list each line (and truncate to last 4).  When you reach the target line you are done.

```
last_3 = []
with open("the_dst_file") as fw:
    with open("the_source_file") as fr:
        for line in fr:
            if line.find("keyword") == 0:
                fw.write(last_3[0] + "\n")
                last_3 = []
                continue
            last_3.append(line)
            last_3 = last_3[-3:]
```

If the format of the file is known in a way that "keyword" will always have at least 3 lines preceding it, and at least 3 lines between instances, then the above is good.  If not, then you would need to guard against the write by checking that the len of `last_3` is at == 3 before pulling off the first element.

Comment: `last_4` is a rolling buffer (list) of four lines. Should also mention that the syntax `[-4:]` is safe even if you get a hit on the first three lines, it silently returns empty-list.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to run this through the whole document. I can't have just one find. Also, I don't need the lines in between the keyword and line -3

Comment: Related solution, using deque [How can I print second and last three lines...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11065216/202229). Sadly that question asks for solutions in both AWK and Python, so it's pretty confused. Should we close as duplicate?

Comment: user2803490: then replace the `break` statement with `f.write`, `print`, `append` or whatever action you want to take. And you only want the third-previous-line `last_4[0]`

Comment: @user2803490 edited.  I didn't understand the requirements (also was doing 4 not 3 for some unknown reason) :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're already using two files, it's as simple as keeping a buffer and writing out the last 3 entries in it when you encounter a match:

```
buf = []  # your buffer
with open("in_file", "r") as f_in, open("out_file", "w") as f_out:  # open the in/out files
    for line in f_in:  # iterate the input file line by line
        if "keyword" in line:  # the current line contains a keyword
            f_out.writelines(buf[-3:])  # write the last 3 lines (or less if not available)
            f_out.write(line)  # write the current line, omit if not needed
            buf = []  # reset the buffer
        else:
            buf.append(line)  # add the current line to the buffer
```

Comment: Related solution, using deque [How can I print second and last three lines...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11065216/202229). Sadly that question asks for solutions in both AWK and Python, so it's pretty confused. Should we close as duplicate?

Comment: This worked, thanks. But I only need one line, the lines in between are not useful

Comment: @user2803490 - You said you want to copy 4 lines, if you just need the fourth line in the _past_ from the current line use `f_out.writelines(buf[-3:-2])`  (to ensure no errors if the buffer doesn't reach that far) and omit writing the current line.