# Python. Read file by line from a point midway through (by byte)

Tags: python, file

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [python: how to jump to a particular line in a huge text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620367/python-how-to-jump-to-a-particular-line-in-a-huge-text-file)

I'm trying to read various lines out of a large (250Mb) file.

The header tells me where certain parts are, i.e. the history subsection of the file starts at byte 241817341.

So is there a way to read the file only starting at that byte, without having to go through the rest of the file first? Something like:

```
file = open(file_name,'r')
history_line = file.readline(241817341)
while history_line != 'End':
    history_line = file.readline()
    [Do something with that line]
```

Is that sort of thing feasible?

Comment: file.seek  I think is what you want ... and maybe file.tell also

Comment: @DarX: That's _close_ -- but when you know you want to start at a specific line number. There's no good way to handle that except reading the whole stupid thing in first. This is starting at a known _byte_, which is different enough that it can be done quickly.

Comment: Cheers guys, seek works great.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
f.seek(0)
print f.readline()
>>> Hello, world!

f.seek(4)
print f.readline()
>>> o, world!
```