# Keep terminal (console) content always starts on top

Tags: python, terminal

I have a lot of content in terminal, books descriptions. When I use:

```
books_text = """Start of text.. end of text."""
print(books_text)
```

I just see on terminal always end, start is hidden on top, that I can't see.

[image: Content starts from bottom, that I do not need]

So, the question, how to print content (with python code commands, statements), that starts from top . Then I can scroll it bottom.

[image: Content starts from top, that I need]

Thanks.

Comment: `python scrip.py | less `

Comment: @MaxNoe, how to do it from python code?

Comment: I doubt this scrolling is a function of python code - it is a function of terminal window.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov, I need the same solution as `git log` command, where i can see all my commits from start to end of window terminal.

Comment: @DmytryiStriletskyi: try : Right click in the terminal -> preferences -> go to Profiles tab -> go to scrolling tab -> increase scrollback

Comment: @SerafeimLoukas, I need to print text, that I can make dynamically from code and print it in loop, for example. And it need to be started from one `python script.py` without any manually settings from user.

Comment: @DmytryiStriletskyi maybe something like this could work for  you: [link to possible solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/620492/5025009). Hope it helps/works

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase the scroll buffer in the profile preference for the terminal application.

It sould be in : *Edit* -> *Profile preferences* -> *Scrolling*