# Python 3 - Looking up line in large text file by line number

Tags: python, text-files, line, handle, file-writing

Title pretty much says it all: I've spent over a day figuring out how to fetch a single line of text out of a large text file through inputting its line number, without success. So far, it seems like the only solutions people are talking about online load the entire text file into a list, but it's simply too large to do so.
The structure of the .txt file I'm working with is literally just a big listing of urls, one per line.

I've tried using `handle.readline()`, but that didn't help the pinpointing of the specific line. Because the file is so large, I can't really justify loading all of its lines into memory using the `handle.readlines()` method, so that's a bust as well. I tried to write a function using a `for index,line in enumerate(handle)` as found online, but that weirdly returns `None`. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: Some code below that does not work:

```
fh = open("file.txt","a+")

def offsetfunc(handle,lineNum):
    line_offset = []
    offset = 0
    for line in handle:
        line_offset.append(offset)
        offset += len(line)
    handle.seek(line_offset[lineNum-1],0)

offsetfunc(fh,1)        #Returns IndexError
print(fh.readline())    #Presumably would be viable, if the previous statement worked?
```

Also, using the `linecache` technique loads the file into memory, so yeah, that's non-viable, too.

Comment: How `handle.readline` is not good solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to jump to a particular line in a huge text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620367/how-to-jump-to-a-particular-line-in-a-huge-text-file)

Comment: It doesn't give the possibility to target the one line I want, simple as that. (The argument for it doesn't specify a line number, but rather a byte.)

Comment: Try providing a code snippet with comments so folks can provide more cohesive answers/suggestions

Comment: There's not much code to provide, as everything given is the large .txt mentioned with the structure described, and furthermore a line number; I tried the technique @Robᵩ offered, as well as the ones in the post above, but none did the trick.

Comment: @Mew all of those should work, as well as Rob's approach. You are going to have to provide a [mcve] if it isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

This program might do what you want:

```
def fetch_one_line(filename, linenumber):
    with open(filename) as handle:
        for n, line in enumerate(handle, 1):
            if n == linenumber:
                return line
    print("OOPS! There aren't enough lines in the file")
    return None

my_line = fetch_one_line('input.txt', 5)
print(repr(my_line))
```

Comment: Still returns "None", though there are plenty of lines!

Comment: Does it print the "OOPS" ?

Comment: Yes, it does print the OOPS.

Comment: Then there are certainly not enough lines in the file. Can you open a text editor and create a 7-line file called "input.txt" and run the above program?

Comment: I did exactly so, and it still returns "OOPS" and None.

Comment: Oh, I might've found my error. Is it wrong for me to have used `handle = open(filename,"r+")` instead of `with open(filename) as handle`? I figured I didn't need the `with` syntax, since the file is already opened at the start of the program.