# Prevent python3 process being 'Killed' by not having enough memory

Tags: python, json, pandas, optimization, memory

I am trying to concatenate two large matrices of numbers, the first one: `features` is an `np.array` shaped `1238,72`, the other is being loaded from a `.json` file as it can be seen on the second line below, it is shaped `1238, 768`. I need to load, concatenate, re-index, split into folds and save each fold in its own folder. The problem is that I get `Killed` on the very first step (reading the `.json` content into `bert`)

```
with open(bert_dir+"/output4layers.json", "r+") as f:
    bert = [json.loads(l)['features'][0]['layers'][0]['values'] for l in f.readlines()]

    bert_post_data = np.concatenate((features,bert), axis=1)
    del bert

    bert_post_data = [bert_post_data[i] for i in index_shuf]
    bert_folds = np.array_split(bert_post_data, num_folds)
    for i in range(num_folds):
        print("saving bert fold ",str(i), bert_folds[i].shape)
        fold_dir = data_dir+"/folds/"+str(i)
        save_p(fold_dir+"/bert", bert_folds[i])
```

Is there a way I can do this more memory efficiently? I mean, there's gotta be a better way... pandas, json lib?

Thanks for your time and attention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620367/how-to-jump-to-a-particular-line-in-a-huge-text-file) when searching for a similar problem. It was not the most voted in the particular question but in my opinion it works better than anything.

The idea is simple: instead of saving a list of strings (one for each line in the document) you save a list of file index positions that refer to each of those lines, then when you want to access its content, you just have to `seek` to this memory position. To do so, a class `LineSeekableFile` comes in handy.

The only problem is that you need to keep the file object (not the whole file!) open during the whole process.

```
class LineSeekableFile:
    def __init__(self, seekable):
        self.fin = seekable
        self.line_map = list() # Map from line index -> file position.
        self.line_map.append(0)
        while seekable.readline():
            self.line_map.append(seekable.tell())

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        # NOTE: This assumes that you're not reading the file sequentially.
        # For that, just use 'for line in file'.
        self.fin.seek(self.line_map[index])
        return self.fin.readline()
```

Then to access it:

```
b_file = bert_dir+"/output4layers.json"

fin = open(b_file, "rt")
BertSeekFile = LineSeekableFile(fin)

b_line = BertSeekFile[idx] #uses the __getitem__ method

fin.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
bert = [json.loads(line)['features'][0]['layers'][0]['values'] for line in f]
```

this way you at least do not read the whole file in memory at once - that being said if the file is huge you must further process what you store in `bert`

Comment: yes, I'm reading other similar issues and seems like the `readlines()` is a big mistake. Apparently I should do the processing line per line. The problem is that I need to apply the reindexing... how can I possibly do that?

Comment: What do you mean to apply the reindexing @LucasAzevedo ?

Comment: before the code snipped shown above, I have "shuffled" the labels assigned to this data. the `index_shuf` variable keeps the order used on that shuffling so I can apply the same shuffling to the matrix resulting from the concatenation of `bert` and `features`. Is there a way of performing this without having to load the whole thing into memory?

Comment: You can just do `bert_post_data[index_shuf]`